# From which Apache version onward is LimitRequestFieldSize no longer hardcoded to 8k max?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, http-headers, limits

Title says it all:
from which version onward is the LimitRequestFieldSize no longer hardcoded to a max. of 8k?

It seems 2.2.15 is still affected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out that it works in 2.2, but you need to increase the max AJP packet size if you have a Tomcat behind it and use mod_proxy_ajp, or else it will still give a 400 Bad Request.

Specifically, set this in Apache:

```
LimitRequestFieldSize 65536
ProxyIOBufferSize 65536
```

and this in Tomcat server.xml on the ajp connector:

```
packetSize="65536"
```

Only setting LimitRequestFieldSize won't do the trick!

Comment: Regarding where to set in Apache: http://serverfault.com/questions/413984/increase-the-value-of-limitrequestfieldsize-in-apache